# How does the Tamron 55-200mm LD macro lens compare to the Canon 55-250mm IS?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, canon, zoom, tamron

I have a Canon 1100d, the standard 18-55mm lens kit, and the 50mm f1.8 lens. I want to buy a zoom lens as I would like to be able to get closer to far away subjects.

I have been looking at both the Tamron and Canon lens. The Tamron is a lot cheaper but the Canon has IS. Could you give me advice on which one to buy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I choose a telephoto zoom lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14599/how-do-i-choose-a-telephoto-zoom-lens)

Comment: for what kind of photography?  outdoors, wildlife, sports, travel?

Answer (score 3):

The Canon model has image stabilization which can come quite in handy when handholding and not using a tripod. It also has a UD element which may improve the chromatic aberration on that lens.  The Canon has 50mm longer reach, which is a benefit.

The Tamron has full time manual focus which is nice to have.

One thing to point out, is that the Tamron is not a macro lens by any stretch, either is the Canon. I believe Tamron markets this lens as such, but don't buy into that.

**From what I am looking at, the Canon is about $25 more on Amazon, so for the image stabilization alone I would say that is worth it. I don't see any compelling reason not to choose the Canon in this situation.**

These are the two lenses I am looking at:

- [Tamron AF 55-200mm Di II Macro Lens for Canon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000CE8IVM)
- [Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4.0-5.6 IS Telephoto Zoom Lens for Canon Digital](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0011NVMO8)